# How to get grouping variables and tibble to a function (possibly group_nest)?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), c=c(7,8,9))

func <- function(...) {
  the_args <- list(...)
  data <- the_args[[1]]
  message(names(data))
}
```

Now I want to make three calls to func, one for each distinct value of `a`.  I thought maybe `group_nest` was my friend, but not quite:

```
# func gets all rows instead of one group at a time
df %>% group_nest(a) %>% func()

# func gets one group at a time, but without a
df %>% group_nest(a) %>% mutate(result=map(data, func))
```

I'd like `func` to be called three times (one for each distinct value of a), each time with all three columns (a, b, c).

Suggestions?

**EDIT**: If I knew the grouping in advance, I could hardcode it in advance:

```
df %>% group_nest(a) %>% mutate(result=map(data, func, a))
```

and inside the function I could set `a <- the_args[[2]]`

However, I want a result that is resilient to different groupings, and passes a complete data frame (data and grouping columns put together), so `func` doesn't have to know anything about how to assemble data.

**EDIT 2**: My actual use case has grouping columns specified more generally, i.e., something like

```
grouping_cols <- c('a')
df %>% group_nest(across(all_of(grouping_cols))) %>%
  mutate(result=map(data, func))
```

Comment: Why not just `df %>% group_nest(a_ = a)`?

Comment: Good god, that seems to work! In the real case, tho, I'm actually passing in `grouping_cols` as a variable, to make this a utility function. Any way to do this more generally? I suppose I could ask a more complicated question with the function and grouping_cols.

Comment: Then how about ``df %>% mutate(across(!!grouping_cols, `(`, .names = "{.col}_")) %>% group_nest(across(paste0(grouping_cols, "_")))``?

Comment: I think this may also work: `df %>% group_nest(foo=across(all_of(grouping_cols)))` ? I'll have to test it more thoroughly

Comment: If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simplest case, you can just

```
df %>% group_nest(a_ = a)
```

And as pointed out by the OP, you can also use a variable for more generic cases

```
df %>% group_nest(foo = across(all_of(grouping_cols)))
```

Another alternative would be

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(!!grouping_cols, `(`, .names = "{.col}_")) %>%
  group_nest(across(paste0(grouping_cols, "_"))
```